# Oracle SQL, how to compare and find mismatches between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

**I've two tabels, in below structure**

```
Table 1

Type  ID  NAME     FROMPOS  SIZE
.doc   1  A Number    4      9
.doc   1  C Number   14     10
.doc   1  Total      24     10
.doc   1  Date       36      8
.doc   1  Data      null    null
```

*Table 2*

```
ID  TYPE   NAME  SEQUENCE SIZE SKIP

1    doc  A Number 1       9    3
1    doc  C Number 2      10    1
1    doc  Total    3      10    0
1    doc  Date     4       8    2
1    doc  Data     5      80    0
1    doc  Type     6       1    0
```

Explanation of Table 1 & Table 2, records in table1 & 2 is structure of a "csv" file

both in table1 & table2 will have type and id, same for all records.

**Table 1 explanation:**

In 1st record has "A Number" & "FROMPOS "(FROM POSITION) value as 4, which means, the first three chars will be blank space and account number will be after that i.e from 4th position to 12th position as the "size" of "A Number" is 9 and for "C Number" we skip a position and begin from 14 to 23 as the "size" of that filed is 10, similarly  for all the other  records. "NULL" in Table1 Columns can be ignored

**Table2 explanation:**

Table2 does not have "FROMPOS" column but has sequence in it, which says the order in which the records should be entered in csv, Table1 is old format and table2 is new format.

So in both the tables the records will actually represents the same format but in different ways.Type, ID and SIZE will be same in both tables

So in Table2,"A Number" has "SEQUENCE" as 1 and "SKIP" is number of character to be skipped, i.e '3' here and so it will start from 4th place, that should match with "FROMPOS" in Table1

Similarly "C Number" has "SEQUENCE" as 2 and "SKIP" as 1, so it will skip 1 place after "A Number" i.e it will skip 13th place and start from 14 and "SIZE" is 10, so end at 23.

Similarly "Total" will begin at 24 as there are no "SKIP" and has length as 10 and end at 34th place. Similary it  is applicable for all the records.

My aim is to write a SQL to ensure that the SEQUENCE,SKIP,SIZE in Table 2 matches with FROMPOS & SIZE in table1

Consider this format in a CSV file,

123456789, 1234567890,1000000,  24/06/20

NOTE: I've tried to join the tables and was succesfull, but I'm unable to write logic to
to ensure that the SEQUENCE,SKIP,SIZE in Table 2 matches with FROMPOS & SIZE in table1.
If they are matching I need 'Success', if they don't match need 'fail'

I'm a novice to SQL, I started to do this project to learn, stuck with this for 4 days.Kindly help to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write query to convert table 2 data in the same format as table 1 using the analytical function and then check it against the table 1 as follows:

```
Select t1.*, t2.*,
       Case when t1.frompos = t2.frompos and t1.size = t2.size 
       then 'SUCCESS' 
       else 'FAIL' 
       end as result
  from table1 t1 join
(Select t.id, t.type, t.name, t.sequence, t.size, t.skip,
       sum(skip+size) over (partition by t.id, t.type order by t.sequence) 
        - size + 1 as frompos,
       t.size
From table2 t) t2
On t1.id = t2.id
And t1.type = t2.type
And t1.name = t2.name
```

**Note**: add condition for handling the null as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
with a as (
    select id, name, frompos, size_, type, 
           row_number() over (partition by id order by frompos) sequence,
           frompos - lag(frompos, 1, 0) over (partition by id order by frompos)
                   - lag(size_, 1, 0) over (partition by id order by frompos)
                   - case when row_number() over (partition by id order by frompos) = 1 
                          then 1 else 0 
                     end as skip
      from table1 )
select id, sequence, a.name, b.name, a.type a_type, b.type b_type, a.frompos, 
       a.size_ as a_size, a.skip as a_skip,
       b.size_ as b_size, b.skip as b_skip
  from a full join table2 b using (id, sequence)
```

gives this result for your data:

```
ID  SEQUENCE NAME      NAME    A_TYPE    B_TYPE  FROMPOS  A_SIZE    A_SKIP  B_SIZE  B_SKIP
1   1        A Number  A Number    .doc    doc     4       9        3          9       3
1   2        C Number  C Number    .doc    doc    14      10        1         10       1
1   3        Total     Total       .doc    doc    24      10        0         10       0
1   4        Date      Date        .doc    doc    36       8        2          8       2
1   5        Data      Data        .doc    doc                     80          0
1   6        Type                          doc                      1          0
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a1b402ce45fa5bfef4ea0723851a4dca)</sup>**

Add `case when` comparing nulls as you wish. First row is slightly different, I had to substract 1. I changed `size` to `size_`, Oracle does not like it as column name.